# Webservice for details of the places

Tags: web-services, api

I want to working on the project for iphone where i have to find the information of particular place of the city.

Example,
i had entere a city name california and i got the long lat of one of the hospital of california including address and phone number.But i want some more detail of the perticluar place  by using webservice.

I had tried to use

1)yelp api
2)Four square api

But it is giving the the 
1)lat-long
2)Adress
3)Phone number
4)Website address

But i want some more detail information related the that perticular place

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Wikipedia API, if the place has an entry it will give you a lot more information:

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Places API of Google:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/